# Grammar for "or" for two version constraints in requirements.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependencies, requirements.txt

I examined PEP440, but couldn't find a reference to a logical or for the case when you have two version constraints for a package, and satisfying either is fine. For example, if you want `requests >= 1.5, < 1.7` or `requests >= 2.0`, how would you put this in requirements.txt?

I tried plugging `requests >= 1.5, < 1.7 or >= 2.0` into `pkg_resources.Requirement`'s `parse` function, and it threw an error, along with `requests >= 1.5, < 1.7 or >= 2.0`. I also tried the above with the SemVer `||`.

Comment: As a workaround you could exclude some versions `!= 1.7.*, != 1.8.*`

Comment: @VPfB Yeah; I'm more looking for a way to convert directly (read: in a straightforward automated fashion) rather than coming up with equivalences...thanks for the suggestion though. I'm starting to think this operation doesn't exist directly, unfortunately.